# Strange folders in my Windows Vista user profile folder

Tags: windows-vista, filesystems

I've been moving all my user files to a second hard drive.  I've moved all the special folders effectively but there are several folders I don't know what to do with.  They appear to be system folders and have a long 36 character string for a name like: `{000f498e-cbc6-4657-9a4e-a468242d6310}`.  They all contain `.inf`, `.cat`, `.dll` files and two of them have subdirectories named `i386`.  Unlike all the other folders in my `c:\users\matt` directory these folder did not have the "Location" option in properties so I couldn't move them that way.

What are these files?  Should I move them manually, leave them alone or delete them?

Comment: Could you give the exact path to some of the folders you mentioned in your question?

Comment: I'm on my phone right now so its hard to enter it but just add the long folder name I mentioned in the question to the the path I cited. The are all in the "matt" directory so just tack it on the end of that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time I've seen those folders, they appear to be left over from a Microsoft update. I usually move them to recycle bin if I can. If you decide to do it, backup your data files as a precaution.